# Sum of Gaussian Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, exponential-sum, summation-method

I am looking for a closed form or an estimation for the sum of a Gaussian sequence expressed as 
$$ \sum_{x=0}^{N-1} e^{\frac{-a}{N^2} \:  x^2}   $$

where $a$ is a constant positive integer.

The interesting part is that I have simulated this sequence using MATLAB for $N=0$ to $10^6$ and found that the result is linear with $N$ and that the line slope is inversely proportional to $a$. However, I believe that the term $N^2$ in the denominator is the reason behind this linearity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,
$$ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\exp\left[-a\left(\frac{x}{N}\right)^2\right]$$
is a Riemann sum for the function $e^{-az^2}$ over the interval $z\in(0,1)$, hence the original sum behaves like 
$$N\int_{0}^{1}e^{-az^2}\,dz =\frac{N}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\,\text{Erf}(\sqrt{a})$$
for any $a>0$ and large enough $N$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast and accurate answer. It also fits the simulation exactly.

Comment: Dear Jack D'Aurizio, could you please send me the reference for Riemann sum for the function $ e^{-az^2}  $ over the interval $z \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @Assem: there is nothing particular about such function, as soon as $f$ is continuous and bounded on $(0,1)$ we have that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)$ approaches $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ by the definition of Riemann integral.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. So what if we have $\sum_{x=0}^{M}\exp\left[-a\left(\frac{x}{N}\right)^2\right]$ where $M<N$  and $M$ can be considered large too. I tried the same trick but it doesn't work because the term $N^2$ is still there.

Comment: I found $\int e^{-ax^2} dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \text{Erf}(x\sqrt{a})$ in some integral tables available online. but I couldn't find a reference. Kindly let me know if you have a reference for this integration. Thank you.