# Sum of M out of N Gaussian Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, exponential-sum, summation-method

I am looking for a closed form, an estimation, or a bound for the sum of $M$ out of $N$ terms of a Gaussian sequence expressed as 
$$ \sum_{x=0}^{M}\exp\left[-a \frac{x^2}{N^2}\right]   $$

where $a$ is a constant positive integer and $M<N$ is the number of arbitrarily chosen terms of the sequence. I believe that the problem here is that the sum will depend on the indices of the $M$ chosen terms. However, we can ignore that to solve the problem initially.

There is an answered question titled [*Sum of Gaussian Sequence*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240593/sum-of-gaussian-sequence). However, that question addressed only the $M=N-1$ case.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer in your previous question!

Comment: Can you link the related question? And this seems closely related to (tail bounds on) [discrete Gaussians](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Discrete_Gaussian) and certain [theta series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function), but I doubt you can get a simpler *exact* expression than this sum.

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you for your comment. I didn't know how to accept the answer. I'm still new on this website. I'm still learning :). Thanks

Comment: @TMM: Thank you for your comment. I've linked the related question.